# PHP как вставить элемент в нужное мне место?

Tags: php, html, html5

Я собираю данные из mysql и хочу их выводить в одном из `<div>`
Как я могу в php указать точное место для вставки данных? И как лучше их вставлять? Я пока костылял через `printf`. Спасибо

```
<div class="left" id="sidel">
        <div> Сюда хочу вставить </div>

</div>

<div class="right" id="sider">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете пользоваться как `print_r()`, так и `echo`.
Первый вариант(Вывод переменной в нужное место):

```php
<?php
$val = '123';
?>

<div class="left" id="sidel">
    <div><?php echo $val;?></div>
</div>
    <div class="right" id="sider">
</div>
```

Второй вариант(Прорисовка частей документа добавляя значение в нужное место):

```php
<?php
$val = '123';
echo '
<div class="left" id="sidel">
    <div>'.$val.'</div>
</div>
    <div class="right" id="sider">123
</div>';
```

Comment: Лучшие практики заключаются в использовании `<?= ... ?>` конструкции

Comment: @mepihindeveloper Максим, Вы конечно правы, но есть одно НО. Для этого необходимо включение шорткодов, что не всегда бывает удобно при миграции проекта в другие системы. Особенно, когда нет доступа к `php.ini`.